# Speech Recognition engines for free?

Tags: speech-recognition

Aside from Microsoft Speech Recogntion, is there any other *reliable* Speech Recognition engines that we can use for free?

Comment: What things about the Microsoft Speech Recognition package do you not like?  What makes it not appropriate for your needs?

Comment: It only runs on Windows which may not be acceptable for every use. Some IT shops have standardized on Unix variants. Someone with existing Linux capacity may not be able to justify Windows licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

Either pocketsphinx or sphinx4 depending on your requirements should fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Also, check out Julius, a large vocabulary open source speech recognizer: http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php